# How to break an infinite loop waiting to accept TCP connection with keyboard interrupt in python

Tags: tcp, keyboard, interrupt

i have a TCP server which is waiting for connections inside an infinite while loop. The problem is i guess as soon as it encounters accept() method it goes to sleep until there is a connection to accept. I want to break out of the loop with a keyboard interrupt but i guess as the function is waiting for connection it just ignores the interrupt..

```
def start_main_server(self):
    print("The Server is ready to recieve")
    socket_threads = list()
    count = 0
    while 1:
        try:
            connectionSocket, addr = self.serversocket.accept()
            print("accepted")
            connectionSocket.send(json.dumps(self.users).encode())
            socket_threads.append(Thread(target=self.login,args=(connectionSocket,)))
            socket_threads[count].start()
            count += 1
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
```

Executable code:

```
    # coding=utf-8
    from socket import *
    port = 12000
    servername = "127.0.0.1"
    connection =socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
    connection.bind((servername,port))
    connection.listen(1)
    print("SERVER STARTED")
    while 1:
        try:
            x = connection.accept()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Keyboard Interrupt Occured")
            break
    print("I am out of loop")
```

Comment: Are you sure it is ignoring the interrupt? If you have tried some code would be helpful :)

Comment: well, I guess it's ignoring. umm actually i am executing the code on command prompt and ctrl+c has no effect so is it because of command prompt or something else.

Comment: thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a runable code example with the issue?

Comment: Is this okay ?? @FormerNcp

Comment: Great! When I run the code and press ctrl+c it exits as expected. output: SERVER STARTED
^CKeyboard Interrupt Occured
I am out of loop

Comment: where did you execute it?? On Command Prompt?? Because for me its not working

Comment: I am using bash in ubuntu 18.04.